# Why are duplicate List Items being created when I Submit an InfoPath form to my list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I seemed to have broken something fundamental. When I edit a SharePoint InfoPath form List Item, it submits an entirely new list! How can I make my Submit button perform the "old" way and just "save" the data to the same item?

Comment: Does your Submit button have rules attached to it? How is your Main Data Connection configured?

Comment: yes  has rules...should I add not to submit to list if ID is not blank?

Comment: No, you have to submit to the list for changes to be saved. How is your main data connection configured? Is the item title using the current date/time? Is this a list or library?

Comment: it is a list, the title doesn't use date/time.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Whenever Info Path is edited and saved it makes a new entry. Would be nice if someone can help with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps to make your file name unique when you edit and save

- Step 1 – Create a Hidden Field
- Step 2 -  Add a Submit data connection
- Step 3 - Add Custom Rules to Submit action

## **Step 1 – Create a Hidden Field**

A hidden field is a field that exists in the data source of the form but is not visible to the user.

The easiest way to create a hidden field is to drag-and-drop a text box control onto the form template’s view. Rename the text box to ‘filename’ and click OK. Then select the filename text box and hit delete to remove the field from the view.

[image: Creating Hidden Field]

## **Step 2 – Add a Submit Data Connection**

Go to Tools, Data Connections and click Add. Create a new Connection to Submit data to a SharePoint document library:
[image: Data Wizard]

[image: Data Wizard2]
Enter the document library, and click the fx button and Insert the field ‘fileName’ in order to give the form submitted the name stored under ‘fileName’. Select ‘Allow overwrite if file exists’.
[image: Data Wizard 3]

Give the data connection a name:
[image: Data Wizard Name]

## **Step 3 – Add Custom Rules to Submit Action**

Go to Tools, Submit Options, and click on Rules.
[image: Submit Option]

Add two rules as follows:

- Rule 1 (fileNameBlank):

  [image: fileNameBlank]
- Set condition: filename is blank:
  [image]
- Set Action 1: Set field’s value filename = concat (Myfield, now()):

Use field on the form i.e., contactName, followed by the function now() to add the date & time and give the form a unique name.

[image]

- Set Action 2: Submit using a data connection (the one created in Step
  2):
  [image]
- Rule 2 (fileNamenotBlank):

[image]

- Set Condition: filename is not blank:
  [image]
- Set Action: Submit using a data connection (the one created in Step
  2):
  [image]

You should now have the following 2 rules setup for Submitting Forms:
[image]

courtesy :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37093/Submitting-an-InfoPath-Form-to-SharePoint-with-a-U